# VBA ADODB Connectig protected excel file

Tags: excel, vba, passwords, adodb

I cannot connect protected Excel file with ADODB. I have a function with arguments: path, file name, password and the responsible code is

Con.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
         "Data Source=$FilePath;" & _
         "Extended Properties=Excel 12.0 Xml;Jet OLEDB:Database Password=$Passs;HDR=Yes"";"

When there is no password it works.

I get autiomation error -2147467259

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing here but I should imagine $FilePath is not correct and that you should substitute in a proper path such as "c:\temp\my.xls".

If you want to check the installation of the drivers etc I would suggest that you start a fresh worksheet with one single sheet and little data in it; and work in more aspects of the file you can't connect to.  So I can see you have ExtendedProperties=Excel 12.0 Xml, I'd suggest you start off with a plain table to test the plumbing and then move on to the Xml.

Answer (score 0):

$FilePath is an argument to a function. It should work the same way as  "c:\temp\my.xls". Anyway  "c:\temp\my.xls" doesn't work also.